# Hecksher-Ohlin production function question

Tags: macroeconomics

I was wondering if anyone here could help me out with this question? We have this production function:

[image]

with these inputs
[image]

Each intermediate good is tradeable and price is given by pj. If we define σ as the elasticity of substitution between skilled and unskilled workers defined as the percentage change in relative demand for low (high) skill workers per percentage change in the relative price of high (low) skill workers, shown by the formula
[image]

How to do we prove [image]